# What are these Insects?

Tags: species-identification, entomology

I live in my hostel in NIT Tiruchchirapalli, in India. My hostel is infested with these beetle-like insects.

[image]

These insects posses a hard shell, if you flick them off the wall, they make a "tap" sound when they hit the ground. They're capable of flying but mostly stay on walls, sometimes even motionless. They also seem to be rather stupid, even for an insect. They don't attempt to escape even in life-or-death situations

### tl;dr

What are these insects?

Comment: they are definitely beetles. size is important to know, and a better picture would be helpful too.

Comment: @picapica They're approximately 0.8cm from head to abdomen. I can't get a better picture as my phone camera can't focus that close up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm trying to answer my own question. I did a bit of searching, and I found out that my insect resembles the **Mupli beetle** the most. From Wikipedia:

> The **Mupli beetle**, *Luprops tristis* (ഓട്ടുറുമ in Malayalam), is a plant detritus eating Darkling beetle found in parts of India. The adult beetle is black and around 8 millimeters (0.31 in) long.

[image]

I hope someone can verify if my findings are correct or not.

Comment: Tenebrionidae is correct. Your ID may be correct.